# Возможно ли создать дочерний сайт в уже существующем сайте на Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

У меня есть сайт на Wordpress на домене допустим `site.test`. И мне нужно сверстать другой сайт который должен быть на этом же самом домене, только в другом каталоге например `site.test/new-site`. Вопрос в том возможно ли ето сделать так что бы, в каталоге **new-site** была своя система файлов(несколько страниц) и чтоб на этих страницах можно было делать запрос в базу и вытягивать данные(посты, записи...) как в стандартных файлах темы (single.php, page.php, archive.php ...)?

Спасибо)

Comment: Лучше вообще НЕ делать во вложенных каталогах. На поддоменах впрочем тоже нежелательный вариант. А "делать запросы в базу" вообще КАТЕГОРИЧЕСКИ не рекомендую. В ВП существует  АПИ.

Comment: Можно, используя мультисайты.